# Why accessing a class field via a struct holding a reference to it is faster in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, performance

A few days ago I checked out the C# implementation of [Binary Trees test](http://benchmarksgame.alioth.debian.org/u64q/program.php?test=binarytrees&lang=csharpcore&id=4) @ Computer Language Benchmark Game, and was weirdly surprised: the tree node there is described as a struct (`TreeNode`) referencing a class (`Next`) which has two fields of a `TreeNode` (strut) type. This obviously looks weird, so I updated this code to use a single class (i.e. ~ `class TreeNode { TreeNode Left, Right }`). My `ItemCheck` implementation was:

```
public int ItemCheck()
{
    if (ReferenceEquals(Left, null)) // Such a node is always a leaf in this test
        return 1;
    return 1 + Left.ItemCheck() + Right.ItemCheck();
}
```

As you may find, it's quite similar to the original implementation. Nevertheless, the performance of this code was ~ 2.2x worse!

Can someone explain why this kind of "optimization" makes sense on .NET? I mostly want to understand what are some other implications of this - of course, if it's not simply a lack in C# / JIT compiler.

A bit more readable version of the same code with a few minor performance improvements can be found here: https://github.com/alexyakunin/BenchmarkGame-CSharp/blob/master/src/BinaryTrees/Program.cs

**Update:** I created an extra project for benchmarking this:

- Code: https://github.com/alexyakunin/BenchmarkGame-CSharp/blob/master/src/Benchmarks/Program.cs
- Benchmarking results: https://github.com/alexyakunin/BenchmarkGame-CSharp/blob/master/src/Benchmarks/BenchmarkDotNet.Artifacts/results/TreeNodeBenchmark-report-github.md

Comment: It really would help if you posted your “code to use a single class” so we could test your claims ourselves.

Comment: As far as I can tell, removing struct increased speed for me. You really should make two complete minimal examples so we can see what you are comparing to what.

Comment: Added reference to the exact code comparing both versions.

Comment: And also, I understood why there is such a difference: struct version stores the last level of the tree inside the prev. one, i.e. there are ~ 2x less allocations in struct-based version of this code.

Comment: @AntonínLejsek as for "removing struct increased speed for me", quite likey you didn't change the condition in CreateNodes, which efficiently made your code to create 2x less nodes. You can verify this by calling CountNodes.

Comment: CreateTreeNodes | 455.46 ns | 2.7411 ns |, |CreateTreeNodeStructs | 593.81 ns | 3.4940 ns |. This is your test on release without visual studio, struct version is slower. But I do not think your code is correct in therms of comparing the same thing. Struct with null Data can not have assigned left or right node. Such struct is equal to null in class version. But you count it as one node in struct version and as zero in class version. You should not alter the CreateTree to match, but the CountNodes: return 1 + (Left == null ? 1 : Left.CountNodes()) + (Right == null ? 1 : Right.CountNodes());

Comment: BenchmarkDotNet=v0.10.5, OS=Windows 10.0.14393
Processor=Intel Core i5-3570K CPU 3.40GHz (Ivy Bridge), ProcessorCount=4
Frequency=3330092 Hz, Resolution=300.2920 ns, Timer=TSC
  [Host]     : Clr 4.0.30319.42000, 32bit LegacyJIT-v4.6.1637.0
  DefaultJob : Clr 4.0.30319.42000, 32bit LegacyJIT-v4.6.1637.0

       CreateTreeNodes | 455.46 ns | 2.7411 ns | 2.4299 ns |
 CreateTreeNodeStructs | 593.81 ns | 3.4940 ns | 3.0973 ns |
        CountTreeNodes |  92.29 ns | 0.5316 ns | 0.4972 ns |
  CountTreeNodeStructs | 109.77 ns | 0.5385 ns | 0.4773 ns |

Comment: @AntonínLejsek looks like you're using a regular .NET, and I am using .NET Core, which is supposed to be faster :)

Comment: @AntonínLejsek the code I referenced is correct -- i.e. struct-based version is supposed to create a "shorter" tree, because all the leafs there are stored right inside structs of above level.

The proof is: it prints the same numbers as the original code.

Maybe one of things that's not quite clear about this test is that it always uses full trees -- that's why it makes sense to compare just one child ref to check whether the current node is a leaf or not.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143732/discussion-between-antonin-lejsek-and-alex-yakunin).